# How to assign extra fee to products for specific category in Magento?

Tags: php, magento, magento-1.9.1

I want for products of a specific category to add an additional field with extra cost for packages, as shown here: https://i.stack.imgur.com/1IyJ7.jpg

Is there any mechanism in Magento by which to do this or require additional module?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use

> Custom Options

in order to fulfill your requirement.

You can add this option from the Magento admin for a particular product. Please refer screen-shot.

[Click to view image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/eAyoG.png)

[image]

Comment: Is there another way to do mass add extra fee for certain categories in the store? Because i need to do it one by one for every product.

Comment: Please refer Judas Kim's posted URL for extension. Thanks.

Comment: I have created 2 custom option fields. Can i make one of them to be selected by default?

Comment: This thing you can do using jQuery/javascript. There is no default option.

Answer (score 0):

The answer that Anx submitted is absolutely right. But you'll have to assign custom option to each product of that category. If you want to repeat the same custom option in multiple products, it will be a lot of manual work.
The simplest solution to apply the same custom option to multiple products is through this free extension.
http://www.magentocommerce.com/magento-connect/custom-option-manger.html

first, apply the custom option as mentioned by Anx, and then use this extension to copy paste it to multiple products. I used it on my site and it worked fine.

Comment: Is there a way that additional fee to be indicated separately in Total? I want users to know for what they give money for exactly.

Comment: That would be customization to magento's core files. I don't know much about that. But one thing i'm certain of. Your total price will raise if the custom option is selected by the customer and they'll know for sure that this additional customization has caused an increase in price.